# How to resolve MemoryError using sklearn knn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

So I just came across this error:

```
Exception has occurred: MemoryError
Unable to allocate 48.0 MiB for an array with shape (64, 256, 256, 3) and data type float32
  File "D:\Uni\MSc\ML\ImageClassification\Task1_KNN.py", line 26, in <module>
    classifier.fit(trainingSet, trainingSet.class_indices)
```

Whilst trying to perform this bit of code using the Fit method from sklearn.

```
classifier = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier()
classifier.fit(trainingSet, trainingSet.class_indices)
```

How do I resolve this as that doesn't seem like a lot of memory to me.

Comment: 48 MB are not much, but the memory may be full before that, and when it tries to allocate those 48MB it can't. I recommend inspecting the memory usage while running those lines of code, and actually see if the memory is full (e.g. task manager in windows)

Comment: Can you provide some more information?